# strophe.js - XMPP Connect to Google account using X-OAUTH2

Tags: xmpp, oauth-2.0, strophe, google-talk

I am using strophe.js for implementing XMPP to connect using google account. I am already using Google OAuth for login into my application using the OAuth token.
How do I use the X-OAUTH2 mechanism to make the `<auth>` request using strophe, rather than  providing the password for the authentication to the XMPP service.
Google's documentation for the X-OAUTH2 authentication states this is the initial `<auth>` request to make:

```
<auth xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"
    mechanism="X-OAUTH2"
    auth:service="oauth2"
    xmlns:auth="http://www.google.com/talk/protocol/auth">
  base64("\0" + user_name + "\0" + oauth_token)
</auth>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm starting to building a client using strophe, to which I'm new too. I guess you'll need to use a proper BOSH connection manager to authenticate to xmpp server with oauth2. I know punjab is popular, you could try to use that, but I'm looking at Node BOSH, as mentioned here [XMPP client Not connecting - using Node Bosh server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600455/xmpp-client-not-connecting-using-node-bosh-server)

Comment: I am using Punjab as the BOSH connection manager to connect to the xmpp server. I am able to authenticate with OAuth2. I followed the facebook connect example, with some changes need for X-OAUTH2.